# SpringBoot Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-security

When I use spring security in springboot, I got an error.

Then I google it, I still can't resolve it.

Then I refer to the spring document(It's easy), I did the configuration,  I still have a problem.

here is my error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key cannot be empty or null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at cn.edu.jit.email.EmailApplication.main(EmailApplication.java:38) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key cannot be empty or null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key cannot be empty or null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasLength(Assert.java:157) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.<init>(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices.<init>(TokenBasedRememberMeServices.java:87) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.RememberMeConfigurer.createTokenBasedRememberMeServices(RememberMeConfigurer.java:395) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.RememberMeConfigurer.createRememberMeServices(RememberMeConfigurer.java:381) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.RememberMeConfigurer.getRememberMeServices(RememberMeConfigurer.java:346) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.RememberMeConfigurer.init(RememberMeConfigurer.java:269) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.RememberMeConfigurer.init(RememberMeConfigurer.java:80) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:290) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:77) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d5f876d6.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$6(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d5f876d6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$784debf.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d5f876d6.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

here is my application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("cn.edu.jit.email")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@MapperScan("cn.edu.jit.email.mapper")
public class EmailApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(EmailApplication.class);
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager txManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EmailApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

here is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
UserDetailsService customUserService() {
    return new CustomUserService();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and() 
            .rememberMe().tokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24 * 7).key("").and() 
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll().and() 
            .logout().permitAll(); 
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserService());
}
}
```

here is CustomUserService

```
@Service
public class CustomUserService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("loaduser " + s);
    User user = userService.getUserByUsername(s);
    if (user == null || user.getIsDel() == 1) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("用户不存在或已被删除");
    }
    List<GrantedAuthority> auths = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
        auths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    }
    System.out.println("load finish");
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(s, user.getPwd(), auths);
}
}
```

here is security's dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is `key("")` in line `.rememberMe().tokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24 * 7).key("")`. Since spring security requires a key for generating encrypted tokens, try passing a non-empty value for a key.

Comment: Could you please guide me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68482157/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-pattern-cannot-be-null-or-empty ?