# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pattern cannot be null or empty

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working on Spring Boot Microservices project using Spring Boot v2.5.2.

Erorr

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pattern cannot be null or empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.example.PhotoAppApiUsersApplication.main(PhotoAppApiUsersApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pattern cannot be null or empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pattern cannot be null or empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:289) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.<init>(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.<init>(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.<init>(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:86) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.<init>(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:358) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at com.example.security.WebSecurity.getAuthenticationFilter(WebSecurity.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.security.WebSecurity.configure(WebSecurity.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:217) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:315) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:93) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at com.example.security.WebSecurity$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$340b667b.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PhotoAppApiConfigServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PhotoAppApiConfigServer</name>
    <description>Photo App Eureka Discovery Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

application.properties

```
server.port=0
spring.application.name=users-ws

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}

spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://locahost:8012

# MYSQL

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.sql.init.platform=mysql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

WebAecurity.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    @Autowired
    private UsersService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
//      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll();
        
        // If Allow only IP address of API gateway  ==> Works well
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasIpAddress(env.getProperty("gateway.ip"))
        .and()
        .addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
        ;
    }

    private AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(userService, env, authenticationManager());
        // This works with login path i.e http://localhost:8082/users-ws/login
//      authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        
        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(env.getProperty("login.url.apth"));
        return authenticationFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
}
```

AuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    
    private UsersService userService;
    private Environment env;
    
    public AuthenticationFilter(UsersService usersService, Environment environment, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.userService = usersService;
        this.env = environment;
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        try {
            LoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginRequestModel.class);

            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getEmail(), 
                            creds.getPassword(), 
                            new ArrayList<>()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return (Authentication) new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                            HttpServletResponse response, 
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        // Get Username (here emailId) from principal object
        String username = ((User) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        
        // Based on Username (i.e emailId) find User from DB
        UserDto userDto = userService.getUserDetailsByEmail(username);
        
        // Create JWT
        String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(userDto.getUserId())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+Long.parseLong(env.getProperty("token.expiration_time"))))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, env.getProperty("toke.secret"))
            .compact();
        
        // Add it into Response Header to be able to pass in the subsequent requets
        response.addHeader("token", token);
        response.addHeader("userId", userDto.getUserId());
        
        System.out.println("TOKEN="+token);
        System.out.println("USERID="+userDto.getUserId());
    }
}
```

Comment: `env.getProperty("login.url.apth")` is probably returning `null` or empty string. `login.url.apth` seems to be a typo. Make sure that environment variable is correctly set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your security configuration, you are using a property placeholder that do not have a matching value in your *application.properties* file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...

    private AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        // ...
        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(env.getProperty("login.url.apth")); // there is no value attributed to the 'login.url.apth' property key
        return authenticationFilter;
    }

    // ...
}
```

If the `login.url.apth` is still defined elsewhere (environment variables, system properties or other property source), then make sure you are using the appropriate key as it already seems there is a typo `login.url.pa[ap]th`.

Comment: Thanks, look like it was Spring Cloud Config server issue which was unable to read properties from git, I fix it , working